# How to make a bootable windows USB in Kali Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, usb, kali-linux

When I tried to boot my PC into Windows 10 I got a screen with a sad face saying unmountable_boot_volume.

After searching it said I needed a Windows 10 USB or CD which I do not have.

I still have access to Kali Linux on my PC by booting up with my SSD.

How can I make a bootable Windows USB with a ISO in Kali Linux OS?

Comment: You could use YUMI application (or an alternative) to create a bootable usb from ISO file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bootable usb using the command `dd` :

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/windows.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=4M
sync
```

example: the output of `fdisk -l` is `/dev/sdb1` :

```
sudo dd if=/home/user/Downloads/windows.iso of=/dev/sdb
sync
```

Answer (score 7):

There is an easier way coming built in with kali linux.

1. Just Browse to the windows iso location
2. Right click on iso
3. Open with other appalication
4. select Disk image writer
5. select your usb device from the drop dows menu
6. click restore
7. click restore again
8. wait until finished
9. boot with usb
10. install Windows

Answer (score 0):

I had major problems with the above solutions as DD made the drive UDF format, I managed to compile woeusb by following instructions [Here](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB), Make sure software-common-properties is up to date.
I also had to edit the changelog in `/woeusb/debian` and add a version number (I used 1.0.1.1) and edit the

```
sudo gdebi ../woeusb_<version>_<architecture>.deb
```

to

```
 sudo dpkg-buildpackage -uc
```

to avoid the signature check.

Obviously running this command whilst in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use Balena  Etcher for Flashing. For downloading iso visit https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10ISO and reboot system. Plugin ur pendrive . Install Windows

Answer (score -2):

There is WinUSB which works quite well.
Add the following rep: ppa:colingille/freshlight
and install WinUSB

Comment: Can you explain further how WinUSB works and why you are recommending it? This answer has been flagged for removal due to the low quality.